# how to increase speed of reading xml with duplicate tags with R

Tags: r, tidyverse, xml2

### The problem

I have many xml files with a structure similar as given below. Each file contains around 10 000 houses.

```
<street>
  <house>
    <id>1</id>
    <door>
      <color>red</color>
    </door>
    <neighbours>
      <id>2</id>
    </neighbours>
  </house>
  <house>
    <id>2</id>
    <postcode>1234</postcode>
    <door>
      <color>green</color>
    </door>
    <neighbours>
      <id>1</id>
      <id>3</id>
    </neighbours>
  </house>
</street>
```

I want to convert each file to a tibble as given below.

```
     id door_color postcode neighbour_id_1 neighbour_id_2
  <dbl> <chr>         <dbl>          <dbl>          <dbl>
1     1 red              NA              2             NA
2     2 green          1234              1              3
```

The problems that I had, were:

1. Column names should be formed by the tag names combined with their parents' names. (e.g. `<door><color> </color></door>` should have the column name 'door_name'.
2. There can be multiple duplicate tags. Duplicate tags should end with '_1', '_2', etc. (e.g. in above example there are multiple neighbour ids).
3. Some houses have tags that other houses do not have (e.g. in above example house 2 has a postcode where house 1 does not).

### My solutions

The first solution I had was

```
xml_to_tibble <- function(file, root_node){
  xml <- read_xml(file) # file is the xml file
  nodes <- xml_find_all(xml, root_node) # root_node is in this case "house"
  nodes_list <- as_list(nodes)
  map_dfr(nodes_list, unlist)
}
```

However, `tidyverse` gives suffices depending on the position of the column. This gives eventually three columns with neighbour ids

```
xml_to_tibble(file, "house")
# A tibble: 2 x 6
  id    door.color neighbours.id postcode neighbours.id...4 neighbours.id...5
  <chr> <chr>      <chr>         <chr>    <chr>             <chr>            
1 1     red        2             NA       NA                NA               
2 2     green      NA            1234     1                 3
```

My second function solves the problem with duplicate tags.

```
xml_to_tibble_v2 <- function(file, root_node){
  xml <- read_xml(file)
  nodes <- xml_find_all(xml, root_node)
  nodes_list <- as_list(nodes)
  nodes_list %>% 
    map(unlist) %>% 
    map_dfr(~set_names(.x, make.unique(names(.x))))
}

xml_to_tibble_v2(file, "house")
  id    door.color neighbours.id postcode neighbours.id.1
  <chr> <chr>      <chr>         <chr>    <chr>          
1 1     red        2             NA       NA             
2 2     green      1             1234     3
```

However, this does not add a suffix to the first duplicate tag.
So I have made a function `make_unique` that gives better column names.

```
make_unique <- function(string, sep="_"){
  duplicates <- string[string %>% duplicated()] %>% unique()
  counts <- list()

  for(i in 1:length(string)){
    str <- string[i]
    if(str %in% duplicates){
      if (str %in% names(counts)){
        counts[[str]] <- counts[[str]] + 1
      } else{
        counts[[str]] <- 1
      }
      string[i] <- paste(str, counts[[str]], sep=sep)
    }
  }
  return(string)
}

xml_to_tibble_v3 <- function(file, root_node){
  xml <- read_xml(file)
  nodes <- xml_find_all(xml, root_node)
  nodes_list <- as_list(nodes)
  nodes_list %>% 
    map(unlist) %>% 
    map_dfr(~set_names(.x, make_unique(names(.x))))
}
xml_to_tibble_v3(file, "house")
  id    door.color neighbours.id postcode neighbours.id_1 neighbours.id_2
  <chr> <chr>      <chr>         <chr>    <chr>           <chr>          
1 1     red        2             NA       NA              NA             
2 2     green      NA            1234     1               3
```

This gives the desired output. (The dots in the column names are easily replaced, I omitted this for now).

This function is good enough, but it takes some time to run.

I have tried other ways, like using the XML package, however these always fail to solve at least one of the three problems.

### Timing

```
# Example xml
file <- rep("<house>
  <id>1</id>
  <door>
  <color>red</color>
  </door>
  <neighbours>
  <id>2</id>
  </neighbours>
  </house>
  <house>
  <id>2</id>
  <postcode>1234</postcode>
  <door>
  <color>green</color>
  </door>
  <neighbours>
  <id>1</id>
  <id>3</id>
  </neighbours>
  </house>", 5000) %>% paste(collapse="")
file <- paste("<street>", file, "</street>")

t = proc.time()
xml_to_tibble_v2(file, "house") # 13.54 seconds
print(proc.time() - t)

t = proc.time()
xml_to_tibble_v3(file, "house") # 14.68 seconds
print(proc.time() - t)
```

### The question

Since there are many files, I would like to read xml files faster. How can I achieve this?

Comment: `xml2::as_list` is very slow. If there are many files, you can just execute your code in multiple R sessions at once to utilize all of your CPU cores

Comment: Further to this (and I'm certainly not saying that danloo is wrong - I've mostly forgotten what little I once knew about `xml2`!): before trying to figure out _how_ to optimise speed, it might be useful to understand _where_ the code is slow. 

For that I'd recommend `profvis` (https://rstudio.github.io/profvis/) which will help you to identify where the code is slow, and from there figure out how to make it faster.